# Read a list from an API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to read a list from an API.
This is the response that API returns to me.

```
[["a",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 
 ["b",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]]
```

Here my call

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("url");
            var strings = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var stringResult = strings.Substring(1, allSymbolsString.Length-2).Split(',');
            List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
            List<string> cleanList = stringResult.ToList();
            foreach (var s in cleanList)
            {
                stringList.Add(Regex.Replace(s, @"...", ""));
            }

            stringList.RemoveAll(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
            List<model> m = new List<model> { };
            foreach (var s in stringList)
            {
                m.Add(new model
                {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                });
            }

            return m;
```

It's work for me but I wonder, is there a shorter way to this? I try to read as a stream but it's thrown me an error. So I write like this.
I hope my question is clear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is returned by the API is a JSON.
Can't you deserialize in into a string[][] ?

If you're using JSON.NET :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(strings);
```

Comment: Fair warning: the equivalent in System.Text.Json will not work because the source JSON contains numbers. You will have to use `object[][]` as the type and convert to strings.